# multivariable derivatives in matlab using diff command

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compute

```
J(i,k) = dF(i)/dm(k)
```

where `J`,`F` and `m` are matrices. What would be the syntax using `diff()`.

Comment: Need more information. If everything is a numeric array, say `F` is 50x50x50 (three variable function), wouldn't you want 3 50x50x50 matrices as the result (each derivative at each grid point)? So your `J` wouldn't be the same size as `F`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: J:200*80 , F: 200*1 , m:80*1

Comment: You data doesn't make sense, and `J(i,k)=dF(i)/dm(k)` doesn't seem well defined if you only have one variable `m`.